# Fail to start browser sync

Tags: node.js, git, sublimetext3, browser-sync

I'm new to these things. I just started to learn web development through a free course in Coursera, and I'm having trouble in setting up the development environment.

That's what I did: installed Sublime Text 3, git and node.js. Created a repository on git, a web page with Sublime and committed it to git.

Now I'm trying to start browser sync but I'm getting this:

```
$ browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*"

[BS] Access URLs:
-------------------------------------
Local: http: //localhost:3000
External: http: //192.168.0.13:3000
-------------------------------------
UI: http: //localhost:3001
UI External: http: //192.168.0.13:3001
-------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[BS] Watching files...
events.js:141
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Browser isn't synchronizing.

Comment: Could you please share your github repo link to take a look at your code?

Comment: Sure.

https://github.com/rodolfoalvesmdo/coursera-rep/tree/gh-pages/site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the mentors of the course helped me with the solution.

The cause of this error was that it was missing the `C:\Windows\System32\` variable in the System Variables. I added it and it solved my problem.